# How to set JVM XMX parameter for SQL Workbench? (increase available memory)

Tags: sql, macos, sql-workbench-j

I'm running Sql Workbench/J and keep running out of memory on a heavy query. (on MAC osx)

I just need to fetch this data once in a blue moon and would like to increase the available memory.

The exact error I get is:

[image]

I found a solution when running from terminal which is to use the command below, but I would like to have one from the Sql Workbench application itself:
java -Xmx4g -jar sqlworkbench.jar

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835997/increase-heap-size-for-sqlworkbench-j

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not a Mac user.

The memory setting that is used for the MacOS launcher is stored in the file `Info.plist` which should be inside the sub-folder `Contents` of the SQL Workbench/J "app" folder (not sure how this is called).

There is already an entry with `-Xmx2048m` present that you can change.