# Increase heap size for sqlworkbench/J in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, sql-workbench-j

I tried running an SQL query on my SQLworkbench on my Ubuntu OS

```
SELECT *,d.dept_name,
 MAX(salary)
OVER(
  PARTITION BY d.dept_name
  ) AS "SAL"
FROM salaries
JOIN dept_emp AS de USING(emp_no)
JOIN departments AS d USING(dept_no)
```

It was running when I suddenly got a pop up message
**sql workbench the system is running low on memory. to prevent data corruption the current operation has been aborted. please increase the heap size with the -xmx parameter.**

I went through some similar post on Stackoverflow and I found this one [Increase heap size for sqlworkbench/J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835997/increase-heap-size-for-sqlworkbench-j/63449338#63449338)

It mentioned running a command `java -Xmx4g -jar sqlworkbench.jar` which I did but when I do that it runs a completely new instance of my Workbench as if I am freshly installing it. Please help I will be doing a lot of `PARTITION BY` queries but I am hindered by this issue.. I checked the free memory and it is **1924MB/1966MB**.

Also when the above pop-up message shows, besides my memory usage spiking up whilst running the query before finally giving that pop-up message... the query timer still keeps counting and my memory usage is as it is as if the query is running, and the option to **cancel execution** is not available, unless I finally close the SQLworkbench then my system memory usage comes back to normal.

Please help I have an 64bit system with 8GB RAM

[SQLworkbench folder files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ewBC.png)

[MEMORY SIZE INFORMATION FOR SQLWORKBENCH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUkY0.png)

Comment: Where exactly did you change the `-Xmx` parameter? You need to add that to the script that you normally use to start SQL Workbench/J. Alternatively use the `-configdir` parameter to specify where your [configuration](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/install.html#config-dir) is located

Comment: If you get that message when running a simple SELECT query, this means you are retrieving a really huge result. What do you want to do with all those rows? If you want export them, use WbExport which doesn't load the whole result into memory. But you need to make sure, the result is retrieved using a cursor as explained [here](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/dbms-problems.html#pg-problems)

Comment: @SQLWorkbenchJ I ran the `java -Xmx4g -jar sqlworkbench.jar` command in my terminal.. is there a way I can edit  the configuration script without having to run the command all the time.. That way I can just run my normal SQLworkbench application and it automatically references the edited configuration script?

Comment: You can edit `sqlworkbench.sh` to set a different memory parameter. If you are not using the provided `sqlworkbench.sh` then you need to edit the script you are using.

Comment: @SQLWorkbenchJ I tried editing `sqlworkbench.sh` but I dont see the memory parameter

Comment: @SQLWorkbenchJ I am going to attach a screenshot of the SQL workbench folder files in the original question

Comment: There is no pre-configered setting. Just add it to the line starting SQL Workbench. E.g. after the `-Xverify:none`. Or add it to the definition of the `OPTS` variable

Comment: @SQLWorkbenchJ Alright I just did a vim into my `sqlworkbench.sh` file and I can see the `-Xverify:none` parameter inside the OPTS variable, please what new parameter am I supposed to add to change the memory configuration... Do I just add `-Xmx4g` alone after the -Xverify:none`

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of `sqlworkbench.sh` are these lines:

```sh
exec "$JAVACMD"  $OPTS \
                -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on \
                -Xverify:none \
                -Dvisualvm.display.name=SQLWorkbenchJ -cp "$cp" workbench.WbStarter "$@"
```

Just add the `-Xmx` paramter where you want, e.g:

```sh
exec "$JAVACMD"  $OPTS \
                -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on \
                -Xverify:none \
                -Xmx4g \
                -Dvisualvm.display.name=SQLWorkbenchJ -cp "$cp" workbench.WbStarter "$@"
```

Comment: Thank you...I did exactly this and I ran my SQLworkbench and checked the memory size in Help--> About but its still the same... I will attach a screenshot of my result in the original question I posted...  Few things you should note : 1) From the moment I started using SQLworkbench I did a copy of the .jar file to my desktop for easy accessibility, so I have duplicates -- one on my desktop and another -- in the SQLworkbench folder, now I have customized the desktop own with themes and all but when I open the other duplicate I dont see my customization..Is this part of the reason for the issue?

Comment: Well, it seems you don't start SQL Workbench using the .sh file but by starting the .jar directly. In that case editing the .sh file obviously won't change anything. You need to start it using the .sh file. I don't understand what "open the duplicate" means. In the end all settings should be stored in `$HOME/.sqlworkbench` unless you manually specified a different config directory.

Comment: Yes, you are right @SQL WorkbenchJ, Thank you so much,  I open my SQLworkbench with the .jar file and also running the `java -Xmx4g -jar sqlworkbench.jar` command works but it is not permanent as I have to keep on specifying the command anytime I need to use the Workbench.... Please is there anyway I can reconfigure my settings in `$HOME/.sqlworkbench` so it remains permanent. By the way I use Ubuntu OS and also thank you so much for the consistent help, Grateful for it.